# Detect if an element is REALLY visible

Tags: javascript

If an element can be seen by human being, ALL of the following must be true:

- `jQuery(elem).is(':visible')` returns `true`. [In jQuery 1.3.2+, an element is visible if its browser-reported offsetWidth or offsetHeight is greater than 0](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.3.2#%3avisible.2F%3ahidden_Overhauled).
- `visibility` style is not `hidden`.
- `opacity` style is not `0`.

However, these do not cover all cases. For instance, one easy case I can think of is, if an element falls outside of one of its ancestors' visible area and that ancestor has a style `overflow: hidden`, then the element can not be seen.

Any existing examples/jQuery plugins/etc. that cover most (if not all) of possibilities?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  What do you do differently if an object is visible or not?

Comment: What about a visible object completely covering the target? Do you consider it visible then?

Comment: I've tried to find a solution for this same issue in the past, but failed. The problem I wanted to solve was to start an animation when a HTML5 canvas element was "exposed". I "fixed" it by just looping the animation.

Comment: Also, if the z-index is greater than anything within its bounds

Comment: My guess is he works for an advertising agency who's anal about measuring advertisement display metrics.

Comment: Other cases of non-visibility: scrolled out of view, clipped by a parent, covered by another object, positioned absolutely or relatively or via margins to be off the visible part of the page, height or width set to 0.

Comment: @Kernel James - Your are a smart guy ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to detect whether an element can be seen by human being or not.
Here are a few more cases you cannot cover:

1. another browser tab is open
2. another application hides the browser window
3. the monitor is turned off
4. the user has her eyes closed
   ... etc.

[end of irony]

Comment: or if the element has a style like `left:-999px`

Comment: or the positioning stacks multiple items on top of eachother with the same z-index