# Detecting if an element is visible on the page with JavaScript or Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, puppeteer

I'm building a framework that crawls websites hosted on our infrastructure to verify there is nothing against our policies. If there is content prohibited, we are taking a screenshot of it among other details.

Obviously, you can't take screenshot if the element is not visible due to being inside of an `overflow: hidden` parent or because there is an absolute element positioned above it.

**Is there a way in 2019 to know if an element can be visible to the human eye?**

Since it's inside Puppeteer I can use either native Puppeteer API or whatever JavaScript library needed since I can inject it to the page.

Example of the problem:

```js
$('#above').html(`You can see green: ${$('#below').is(':visible')}. But can you really?`)
```

```css
#above {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#below {
  width: 440;
  height: 200;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="above"></div>
<div id="below"></div>
```

(Yes, I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12154278/601179) was asked, but it was 7 years ago and much was changed since and I can also use puppeteer which in his case was not possible).

Comment: *Is there a way in 2019 to know if an element can be visible to the human eye?* Definitely not with 100% certainty.

Comment: @MiXT4PE well, 50% is better than 40%, so whatever improves the odds is helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

I never did this, but the [hover](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#pagehoverselector) function will fail if the element is not visible or "hoverable". You could do something like this:

```js
let error = null;
await page.hover('yourSelector').catch(e => error = e);
if (!error) {
   //The element should be visible here.
}
```

Comment: This scenario I believe is considered to be visible for puppeteer (it's for screenshot), but I'll check it shortly.

Comment: As I suspected, it doesn't considered to be invisible for puppeteer. :( Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I found a way (thanks *@hardkoded* for planting the idea in my head...)
I didn't test it on all edge cases, but it does seem to work on my example.

Basically I'm adding an eventListener for `mouseover` event that sets a boolean flag and then calling puppeteer's `hover` function that moves the mouse to the center of the element.
If the flag is set, the element is visible.

```
await page.goto('c:/temp/code.html')
const el = await page.$('#below')
await page.evaluate(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    this.setAttribute('mouseover-worked', 'true')
    console.log('hovered!!!')
  })
}, el)
await el.hover()
const hovering_works = await page.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('mouseover-worked'), el)
console.log(hovering_works)
```

If someone finds a flaw, please let me know...

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way built into the puppeteer library to check this. You can give a `{ visible: false }` option to the [`page.waitForSelector`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/1de9906260269491c9011fcab33a58e280603fd3/lib/DOMWorld.js#L505) function that will check or actually wait until an element is visible:

```js
const element = await page.waitForSelector('#selector', { visible: true });
```

This will do a decent check. See the full code of the function [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/1de9906260269491c9011fcab33a58e280603fd3/lib/DOMWorld.js#L505). It will check the following:

- Does the element exist?
- Is the element not hidden (`style.visibility !== 'hidden'`) according to `window.getComputedStyle`?
- Has the element a `height`/`width`/`top`/`bottom` greater than `0` according to `element.getBoundingClientRect()`?

The latter case would also cover your example code as the `#below` element should be having a height of `0`. So it's a decent check but you will always be able to construct cases in which the code does not work. If you want to cover more edge cases, you can also expand the approach of the puppeteer devs.

**Full code sample**

As the function will not resolve if the element does not exist, you have to use a small helper Promise to timeout the check:

```js
const element = await Promise.race([
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 200)), // resolves without value after 200ms
    page.waitForSelector('#selector', { visible: true })
]);
if (element) {
    // element is visible
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is considered to be visible by all the checks you suggested. I tested it. Did you test your suggestion?

Comment: I just briefly tested it. I opened the DevTools in Chrome on the expanded code snippet and executed `document.querySelector('#below').getBoundingClientRect()`, which returned `{ height: 0, ... }` for me. Therefore, I assumed the check would work. I guess the result from `getBoundingClientRect()` is different for the element you are checking. Sorry :(

Comment: No need for the promise wrapper here as page.waitForSelector takes a timeout argument as well as a visible argument.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can using [`elementHandle.boundingBox()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.2.1&show=api-elementhandleboundingbox)

It will return a Promise that show a bounding box of the element (relative to the main frame), or null if the element is not visible.

The snippet example:

```js
      const loadMoreButton = await getDataPage.$(
        'button.ao-tour-reviews__load-more-cta.js-ao-tour-reviews__load-more-cta'
      );

      const buttonVisible = await loadMoreButton.boundingBox();

      if (buttonVisible) {
        await loadMoreButton.click().catch((e) => {
          console.log(': ' + e)
        });
      }
```